# Unregister Broadcast Receiver in a static way - Android

Tags: java, android, static, broadcastreceiver

I would like to register a broadcast receiver in Activity A, and unregister it in Activity B.
I have this code which is static:

```
private static BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver;

    public static void registerSMSBR(Context context){
        smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED");
        context.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
    }

    public static void unregisterSMSreceiver(Context context){
        if(smsReceiver != null){
            context.unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
        }
    }
```

I've added the right permission and I'm calling `registerSMSBR(context);` 
in Activity A and 
`unregisterSMSreceiver(context);` 
in Activity B.

The problem is that "unregisterSMSreceiver(context)" doesn't unregister and onReceive still runs on new sms message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

May be you use activities as context in both cases. So, you register a receiver in one context. and unregister it in another(where it is absent). Try to use `activity.getApplicationContext()` in both cases.

Comment: this is a good idea. but i'm already using getApplicationContext() in both